# How to test Django Querysets are equal using pytest-django

Tags: python, django, django-testing, pytest-django

What's the best / most readable way to assert two querysets are equal? I've come up with a few solutions:

```
# option 1
assert sorted(qs1.values_list("pk", flat=True)) == sorted(qs2.values_list("pk", flat=True))

# option 2 (need to assert length first because set might remove duplicates)
assert len(qs1) == len(qs2)
assert set(qs1) == set(qs2)
```

I know Django has a method [django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual). Does pytest-django have something similar? I don't see it in the [documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's there in the starting lines of the link that you suggested:

> Assertions
> All of Django’s TestCase Assertions are available in pytest_django.asserts,
> e.g.
> `from pytest_django.asserts import assertTemplateUsed`

Similarly you can use, from `pytest_django.asserts import assertQuerysetEqual`